# error upload files, php and angularjs connexion aborted

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, ionic-framework

i'm trying to upload files using angularJs and PHP.
the exact error message is like that:

```
ionic.bundle.js:26799 TypeError: Cannot read property 'state_code' of null
    at controllers.js:1718
    at services.js:298
    at processQueue (ionic.bundle.js:29132)
    at ionic.bundle.js:29148
    at Scope.$eval (ionic.bundle.js:30400)
    at Scope.$digest (ionic.bundle.js:30216)
    at Scope.$apply (ionic.bundle.js:30508)
    at done (ionic.bundle.js:24829)
    at completeRequest (ionic.bundle.js:25027)
    at XMLHttpRequest.requestError (ionic.bundle.js:24978)
```

html form:

```
<div class="footer row">
            <div class="text-center col col-50">
                <div id="FileUpload">
                    <input type="file" accept="image/*;capture=camera" id="BrowserHidden" ng-model="upload_file"/>
                    <div class="text-center">
                        <button class="button custom-button"  type="submit">
                            Charger un fichier
                        </button>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
            <div class="text-center col col-50">
                <button class="button custom-button" ng-click="SubmitUpload();">
                    Suivant
                </button>
```

controllers.js looks like that at 1718 :

```
if (document.getElementById("BrowserHidden") != undefined) {
                document.getElementById("BrowserHidden").onchange = function () {
                    var reader = new FileReader();
                    reader.onload = function (e) {
                        // get loaded data and render thumbnail.
                        document.getElementById("image").src = e.target.result;
                    };

                    // read the image file as a data URL.
                    reader.readAsDataURL(this.files[0]);
                    $scope.fileUploaded = this.files[0];
                  var image_name=this.files[0].name;
                    $scope.image_name=image_name;
                    localStorage.setItem("piece1", $scope.image_name);
                };
            }
            $scope.SubmitUpload = function () {
                if ($scope.fileUploaded == undefined) {
                    $ionicPopup.alert({
                        title: "Alert",
                        template: "Veuillez sélectionner une photo de votre carte d'identité ou passeport"
                    });
                } else {
                    UploadService.uploadFile($scope.fileUploaded, getLocalItem("id_user", localStorageService), function (data) {
  ligne 1718->                        console.log(data)
                        if (data.state_code == 200) {
                            //$state.go('success_upload');
                            $state.go('signaletique_upload_2');
                        } else {

                          $ionicPopup.alert({
                                title: "Alert",
                                template: data.message
                            }); 
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
```

service.js

```
.factory('UploadService', function ($http, $ionicLoading, Upload) {
        return {
            uploadFile: function (_photo, _formID, callback) {
                $ionicLoading.show();
                Upload.upload({
                    url: UPLOAD_FILE,
                    headers: {
   'Content-Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' 
   // or  'Content-Type':'application/json'
 },


       data: {photo: _photo, 'user_id': _formID}

                }).then(function (resp) {
       ligne 298->             callback(resp.data);
                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                }, function (resp) {
                    callback(resp.data);
                    $ionicLoading.hide();
                }, function (evt) {

                });
            }
        }
    })
```

function.js

```
var UPLOAD_FILE =  URL_RACINE +'php/ws_upload_file.php';
```

ws_upload_file.php

```
include_once 'config.php';
$id_user = $data['user_id'];
$uploads_dir = 'uploads';
$tmp_name = $_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"];
$name = $_FILES["photo"]["name"];

$ext = pathinfo($name, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
if(!in_array($ext,['png','jpg','jpeg'])){
    echo json_encode(array('status'=>'Error','state_code' => '101','message'=>'fichier invalide'));
    die;
}else{
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, "$uploads_dir/$name");
}
```

- evrything used to work fine , but now i get an error off connexion
  aborted ,when i try to uplaod file. so i figure out a solution is to
  add the host name before calling the ws php to upload file
  exp(http://195.25.55.21:81/php/ws_upload.php) but this work only for
  my local machine others get connection forbiden even that they can
  access to the domaine they get only error permission when they try to
  upload files.
- To make it more confusing when i try to call the function like
  that('/php/ws_upload.php') only files who has small taill accepted ,
  even in the php.ini by default i get 2M , note with this method i get
  connection aborted failed to load ressource /php/ws_upload.php.
- i downlond the project and i tried in my machine evrything works fine
  , means that it's not an eror in my code
- i'm just unsure as to what could be stopping the upload,quiring minds want to know. Thank you